# Remote Desktop from UNIX to Windows

Tags: windows, unix, ssh, remote, desktop

You know how you can enable x11 forwarding and through putty when you use a program on the remote UNIX machine, the visuals of it (GUI, etc.) appear on your end?

What I'm trying to do is instead of individual applications being displayed to me, having the entire desktop of the UNIX machine being displayed on my Windows machine and able to be interacted with.

Comment: Did you look at VNC?

Comment: VNC will not work for me since the free version is not compatible with windows 7. I am looking for a free alternative. I know a buddy of mine has done something like this before but I don't know how specifically. I could ask him though.

Comment: I haven't tried it but a quick google search shows that there are many VNC clients compatible with windows 7

Comment: Ah, I must have looked at one type of vnc while it appears there are many, thank you, I will take a look.

Comment: TightVNC on Windows 7 works well and you don't have to license it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no shortage of options.

- Linux server: [TurboVNC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualgl/files/TurboVNC/), [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/), or [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/)
  Windows client: [UltraVNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraVNC), [TurboVNC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualgl/files/TurboVNC/), [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/), or [ssvnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/ssvnc.html)

  - Also, [RealVNC 4.0](http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.0/) is still open-source.
- Linux server: [Xrdp](http://www.xrdp.org/)
  Windows client: can use Microsoft's `mstsc.exe`
- Linux server: [FreeNX](http://freenx.berlios.de/)
  Windows client: [NoMachine](http://nomachine.com/)
- [winswitch](http://winswitch.org/)

Comment: Thank you I will take a look, I guess its just the one I looked at (which I assumed was the only vnc) was not compatible with windows 7 for free.